# Convert @<text> </text> syntax to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, razor

The following code, written for a webgrid that used in mvc view.
I want the equivalent and converted to vb syntax

```
grid.Columns(grid.Column(header: "Assign?", format:@<text><input class="check-box"  id="assignChkBx"name="assignChkBx" type="checkbox" value="@item.Id"/></text>))
```

Comment: Try with this definition: `grid.Columns(grid.Column(header := "Assign?", format := @<text><input class="check-box" id="assignChkBx" name="assignChkBx" type="checkbox" value="@item.Id"/></text>))`. Note if the `<text>` contained inside constructor, it is necessary to add `Sub() ... End Sub` block.

Comment: Thank you for your support.
I tried both code, but did not work.  `...@<text>input> ....  </text></input>...` and `...sub() @<text>input> ....  </text></input> End Sub()`